# Compare subquery result with pair of 2 parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I need to compare 2 parameters in select query with 2 parameters in subquery.
Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pupil 
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM bad_names)
```

This example contains only one parameter to compare. But what if I need to compare subquery result with pair of 2 parameters?
This will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pupil 
WHERE name||lastname NOT IN (
    SELECT name||lastname FROM bad_name_lastname_combinations)
```

So string concatenation is the only way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL is flexible enough to do this with a [*row constructor* and NOT IN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN):

> ```
> row_constructor NOT IN (subquery)
> ```
>
> The left-hand side of this form of `NOT IN` is a row constructor, as described in Section 4.2.13. The right-hand side is a parenthesized subquery, which must return exactly as many columns as there are expressions in the left-hand row. The left-hand expressions are evaluated and compared row-wise to each row of the subquery result. The result of `NOT IN` is "true" if only unequal subquery rows are found (including the case where the subquery returns no rows). The result is "false" if any equal row is found.

So you can do it in the straight forward way if you write the `row_constructor` properly:

```
select *
from pupil
where (name, lastname) not in (
  select name, lastname
  from bad_last_name_combinations
)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a6863/1

Comment: i have same issue with mysql........ and i wanna compare numerically (>= or <=). How did i do that, plz help.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM pupil p left outer join
     bad_name_lastname_combinations bnlc
     on p.name = bnlc.name and p.lastname = bnlc.lastname
WHERE bnlc.name is null;
```

Comment: @user1561346 . . . I prefer the `left outer join` approach because it is standard SQL and supported by any database.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  *
from    pupil p
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    bad_names bn
        where   bn.name = p.name
                and bn.lastname = p.lastname
        )
```

Comment: Please explain how you arrived to your solution, and not just giving the answer to the OP so that the answer is more general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NOT EXISTS command

```
SELECT * 
FROM pupil p
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM bad_name_lastname_combinations b
  WHERE b.name = p.name AND b.lastname = p.lastname)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. If you change OR to AND it will work as it should.